# Error Router inside Router in React + Electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have in my applcation a React Router and inside the component called by React Router I have another React Router.

App.jsx

```
<HashRouter> 
       <ListItemText primary={<Link style={styleRoutesMenu} to={'/relatorioView'}><p className="index__menuDescricao">Relatórios Financeiros</p></Link>}/>
       <Route path='/relatorioView' component={() => <RelatorioView tituloDaTela={setTituloDaTela}/>}/>
</HashRouter> )
```

And Relatorio.jsx

```
<HashRouter>
       <Redirect to="/diarioView" />
       <Route path='/diarioView' component={() => <DiarioView/>}/>
       <Link style={{textDecoration: "none"}} to={'/diarioView'}>
            <button>Open</button>
       </Link>
</HashRouter>
```

If I set in my index.js to open Relatorio.jsx, my route works fine. But if I set in index.js to open App.jsx and there I try to open Relatorio.jsx, it doesn't work. My diarioView doesn't show up. It's like my screen has nothing.

It works: if I just open the Relatorio.jsx and try to use
[Works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5FSv.png)

It doesn't work: if I try to open by using the react inside the react
[if I try to open by using the react inside the react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIL2N.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out.
Because my routes are nested, I need to continue the URL in Relatorio.jsx
So:

```
<HashRouter>
       <Redirect to="**/relatorioView/**diarioView" />
       <Route path='/diarioView' component={() => <DiarioView/>}/>
       <Link style={{textDecoration: "none"}} to={'**/relatorioView/**diarioView'}>
            <button>Open</button>
       </Link>
</HashRouter>
```